# Entry/Exit Data for UK

Tags: united-kingdom, visa

I will be applying for a tourist visa as a Non-EU national to visit the UK with my husband.

As part of this process I will be required to provide entry/exit dates. As I did not buy my last exit ticket nor have contact with the person who did buy my flight - how do I find out this information? Will this data still be stored (from Jan 2015)? Does it matter that I have a new passport?

Comment: Even though you didn't purchase the ticket, didn't you have a boarding pass, paper or electronic, or anything else that tells when you left and returned to your place of residence? Do you have your old passport?

Comment: Is your husband also a non-EU national?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. My husband is a UK born citizen. I have searched everywhere, asked everyone and still nothing to support my dates, it's a bit of a pickle and I'm a little worried. My passport was stolen so I do not have that either.

Answer (score 2):

Should you find it necessary to provide exact details, you can obtain your entry and exit records directly from the UKVI. It is done through a [Subject Access Request (SAR)](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/580093/SAR_Form_Dec_2016.docx).

> **[Request your personal data from UK Visas and Immigration](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/requests-for-personal-data-uk-visas-and-immigration)**
>
> The Data Protection Act 1998 determines how we process personal data (information relating to living people). The act means you can ask to access the information we hold about you.
>
> These requests are called subject access requests. You should expect a response from us within 40 days.